# throw new Error(this.name + '.' + Utils.lowercaseFirst(Type.toString())

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a code create model. but when run it throw error

contactstatus.js:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var contact_status = sequelize.define('lk_contactstatus', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: false
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING(32),
    lk_recordstatusid: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        contact_status.belongsTo(
          models.r_status,
          {foreignKey: 'lk_recordstatusid'}
        );
      }
    }
  });

  return contact_status;
};
```

recordstatus.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var r_status = sequelize.define('lk_record_status', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: false
    },

    name: DataTypes.STRING(16)
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  return r_status;
};
```

> called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model at
>   null.belongsTo (F:\CONG
>   VIEC\Auvene\sampleczarapi\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:95:13)
>        at sequelize.define.classMethods.associate (F:\CONG VIEC\Auvene\sampleczarapi\models\facp-contact\contact_type.js:10:22)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling belongsTo with something that's not a model (**called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model**).

You defined the model name as ***lk_record_status*** but then you call it as ***r_status***.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var contact_status = sequelize.define('lk_contactstatus', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: false
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING(32),
    lk_recordstatusid: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        contact_status.belongsTo(
          models.lk_record_status,
          {foreignKey: 'lk_recordstatusid'}
        );
      }
    }
  });

  return contact_status;
};
```